# Raspberry PI2 under voltage with a standard microsoft webcam connected.

Tags: webcam

I am attempted to setup my octopi IOS to connect to my 3d printer. I've got everything connected and configured however,  noticed during the boot process,  when the USB webcam is connected,  i get the "under voltage"  message received and the octopi doesn't load.  Removing the webcam,  everything seem to work.

I am going to check a different camera.  But not quite sure why a recommended webcam supposedly supported by the octopi IOS,  doesn't work.  Do I need a different power supply for the pi?  any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have very little knowledge of these PIs.   thanks

Comment: Are using a full 2500ma 5V power supply?  When you do, there is 1500ma available for all four USB ports total.  That is certainly enough for a Lifecam.

Answer (score 1):

It is not unusual for high power USB devices to have problems with the Pi. (External HDD are the principal offenders.)

See **How much current can draw from the USB ports** in [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations) - this can be increased to 1200mA on the Pi2.

This MAY solve your problem (provided your supply is adequate - most aren't).
If not the only solution is a **powered hub**.

Answer (score 1):

Webcams are quite power-hungry devices, superseded only by hard drives and the like. For instance, Logitech [claims](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=13631) that their top of the range webcams can consume as much as 500mA, which is the maximum for a compliant USB2 device. You have to calculate the total peak current your system can require and make sure your PSU can provide that without going lower than 4.75V on the Pi side (that is, after all losses in cables and connectors).